# How to write proper ES6 class in Express API?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, babeljs

I am doing a Node.js REST tutorial with Express. Trying to make a class for `GET` route.

```js
// get.js

class Get {
  constructor({ knex } = {}) {
    this.knex = knex;
  }

  async getAll(_req, res, next) {
    try {
      // Get from database
      const users = await this.knex('users').select();

      // Return OK status code and users
      res.status(200).send(users);
    } catch (error) {
      // Return BAD REQUEST status code
      return error;
    }
  }
}

export default Get;
```

And I pass the `knex` to the `getUser` class:

```js
// routes.js

import knex from './libs/knex';
import { default as getUser } from './user/Get';

const router = Router();
const userGet = new getUser({ knex });

router.get('/users', userGet.getAll);
```

But I got an error when I make a `GET` request at `/users`:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'knex' of undefined
    at knex (/home/rest-tutorial/src/user/Get.js:14:32)
```

What I am doing wrong?
Please help.

P.S. I use `babel@7.5.5` by the way, also installed `@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties`

Comment: try adding `this.getAll = this.getAll.bind(this)` in the `Get` `constructor` - or even `router.get('/users', userGet.getAll.bind(userGet);`

Comment: @JaromandaX - Why don't you write an answer?

Comment: wasn't sure it was that simple :D also, I don't think I can explain it well enough, I'd have to "borrow" from the 300 other times it was answered

Comment: @JaromandaX It works! :) Thanks!